# Unable to fetch form data in controller using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to angularjs. So from [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5EyJOpj4RyM), I am trying to develop my first angularjs application. But I was stuck at the 25th minute of the video where the tutor basically trying to bind the `Save` user button with the controller and he is able to do so. The data is submitted to the controller in form of array. But when I am trying to do the exact same thing, I am getting an empty array. Why?

JS version:- `bootstrap-3.3.7` with `angularjs 1.6.4`

**index.html**

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">New Users Registration</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Username</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="newuser.username">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="newuser.email">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Full Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="newuser.fullname">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group"> 
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="saveuser()" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

my **app.js** is

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myController',function($scope){
    console.log("My controller");
    $scope.newuser = {};
    $scope.users = [
        {username:"Satya",fullname:"Satya",email:"satya@gmail.com"}
    ];
    $scope.saveuser = function(){
        $scope.users.push($scope.newuser);
        $scope.newuser = {};
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it's my mistake. Apparently, the input type should be `text` type. In my HTML file, I kept it as `email` type. Changing that resolve the problem. I am not sure but this might be bootstrap which validates the form data before processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass the user as an argument to the function:

```
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="saveuser(newuser)" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
    </div>  

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myController',function($scope){
  $scope.newuser = {};
  $scope.users = [
    {username:"Satya",fullname:"Satya",email:"satya@gmail.com"}
  ];
  $scope.saveuser = function(newuser){
    $scope.users.push(newuser);
    $scope.newuser = {};
  };
});
```

Comment: is there any other way I can send form data to the controller??